# How to open spark web ui while running pyspark code in pycharm?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am running pyspark program in pycharm local on windows 10 machine . I want to open spark web ui to monitor job and understand metrics showed over spark web ui . While running same code on jupyter I can access web ui but when I run program using pycharm I do not see option to access spark web ui , even I tried url local:4040 or localhost:4041 but , this did not work .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure which **port that ui** can access in **sparksession**.

**`Example:`**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").\
appName("Word Count").\
config("spark.driver.bindAddress","localhost").\
config("spark.ui.port","4050").\
getOrCreate()
```

Now once the spark session initialized then we can access spark ui in `http://localhost:4050/jobs/` **`until the pycharm job finished executing`**.

In case if the port is not able to access at the time then in your log spark prints where does we can access the **spark ui**.

**`Sample log:`**

`2020-08-17 14:39:37 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4050. Attempting port 4051.`

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I was using url till port without mentioning /jobs , even without configuring config("spark.ui.port","4050").\  , default port like 4040 or 4041 whatever spark uses could be used for web ui url .

Comment: @Shu How to access the UI even when the session gets completed. Because after the code executes, I am not able to access localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `http://localhost:4040/jobs/`?

Works for me ;)

My code has the likes of:

```
import pyspark as spark
sc = spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(spark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
ss = spark.sql.SparkSession(sc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain your spark session open.

To keep your session open within python script in Pycharm add `input("Press enter to terminate")` before your `spark.stop()`.

Until you press `enter` the session remains open & you can access spark Web UI.

Comment: You could use spark history server in case you don't want to keep spark job hanging. spark history server replays spark logs to build a spark ui. Notice that there is no need to keep spark session active. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#spark-history-server-configuration-options